# How can I issue a LINQ query to a SQL Server to check if a column value starts with a word?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have this already

```
        if (options.English != null) query = query
            .Where(w => w.English.Contains(options.English));
```

What I would like to do is to extend this (maybe with another if clause) to make it so that if:

- a user enters `^abc` then my query would check if the word starts with "abc".
- a user `abc` then it would check if the column contains "abc"

I am using a SQL Server back-end database. Could anyone give me a suggestion as to how I could implement this functionality.

Comment: You'd have to check for the `^` and remove it and then use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`.

Comment: Oh, lawd, just look at the first character and if it's a control character then strip it off and handle it the way you want, defaulting if it isn't a control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put that choice in a conditional statement:

```
IQueryable<Whatever> query = ...;

if (searchText.StartsWith("^"))
{
    query = query.Where(w => w.English.StartsWith(searchText.Substring(1)));
}
else
{
    query = query.Where(w => w.English.Contains(searchText));
}
```

You can also do the same comparison inline, but that'll generate very ugly SQL, if it even works:

```
query = query.Where(w => 
        searchText.StartsWith("^")
            ? w.English.StartsWith(searchText.Substring(1))
            : w.English.Contains(searchText));
```

Do note that you generally don't want to search text using SQL, as that results in a pretty poor user experience. Take a look at full-text indexing.

Comment: You'd also need to remove the `^` before passing it to `StartsWith`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're using Entity Framework, you can use the `StartsWith()` and `EndsWith()` methods, to achieve the same results as Contains() except only at the beginning or the end of a string. It will generate the code for you.

Then simply create conditional statements in your code, in order to determine which one of the methods you should use.

**Some word of advice:**

There might be a bug with EF Core, in which it turns `StartsWith("string")` into `LIKE "string%"` which might yield incorrect results with strings, containing wildcard characters such as "_".

So I'd advise you to use plain SQL with EF Core, and given that you're using SQL Server as a DBMS, query like that:

```
if (searchText.StartsWith("^"))
{
    var result = query.FromSql($"SELECT something FROM table WHERE PATINDEX({searchText.Substring(1)}, something) = 1");
}
else
{
    var result = query.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM table WHERE PATINDEX({searchText.Substring(1)}, something ) <> 0");
}
```

With `PATINDEX()` you will get correct results even if your pattern string contains wildcard characters - escaping potential bugs with relying on `StartsWith()` and `EndsWith()` to generate proper SQL code.

But that's only for EF Core, EF 6 works like a charm the way other people answered :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (options.English != null) 
{
    bool englishStartsWith = options.English.StartsWith("^");
    if(englishStartsWith)
    {
       query = query.Where(w => w.English.StartsWith(options.English.Substring(1)));
    }
    else
    {
       query = query.Where(w => w.English.Contains(options.English));
    }
}
```